# IIS: public website

Tags: iis

I've hosted my website and I can see it well through: 192.168.247.1/api/products.
Now, I would like to make it public on the internet.

I did:

1. IIS Manager -> Bindings -> add: ip=104.56.153.245, port=42485.
2. Forwarding port by the router's interface (made port 42485 available).
3. Checking windows firewall will not interfere.
   *The public ip is what I've got by whatismyip website.

So I tried to get: 104.56.153.245:42485/api/products,
but all I got was a timeout.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer letting the Internal IP binding be as it is in IIS.

Then setup a port forwarding route from external IP to the internal one.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Rahul Soni!
It was one of two things that had solved my problem.

In general, I had a confusion between 192.168.x.x IP and 10.0.0.x IP,
my advice: use merely the latter one.

1) The binding of IIS Manager should contain 10.0.0.x IP with some port (42485  in my case).
2) Forwarding port by the router's interface (making port 42485 available) should also forward to 10.0.0.x IP!

The way of checking whether the port is right or not, would be done by the site: http://www.canyouseeme.org/
or http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

Hope this would help other people with that irritating problem.